How to convert any assembly in cgr format
I am facing to find the API for conversion of assembly in cgr format
there are api available in ds help viewer but the implementation of code is not available
The APi are catiexchangeproduct
Catiexchangetesselatedrepressentation
But when i am implementing i am facing error are there are absenct of examples
